# What is the 'rank' in 'rank insubordination'?

Tags: meaning, military

The phrase "rank insubordination" is used at times (e.g. [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/entertainment/books/2004/10/31/rank-insubordination/5f567e30-5ee0-4e8f-ad0b-e0c67653d8ef/), [Salon.com](https://www.salon.com/2006/05/22/miller_49/), and [University of East Anglia](https://research-portal.uea.ac.uk/en/publications/rank-insubordination-disobedience-and-disinheritance-amongst-the-)) to describe disregarding a superior's orders.

But what exactly is the *rank* for? It's obviously modifying *insubordination*, but *rank* has three senses that could be relevant. I am wondering which of them is intended by the phrase.

- Is *rank* being used as an adjective meaning "foul or offensive"?
- Is *rank* being used as an adjective meaning "flagrant"?
- Is *rank* being used as a noun referring to one's position within a hierarchy?

Etymologically and in use, which sense is intended?

Comment: And that's how you show the research and explain where the confusion lies. Bravo editor.

Comment: I disagree. There is no evidence of actual research here, merely stabs in the dark at potential meanings without any reason for choosing those meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you can't find any definition that fits, however most dictionaries include a fitting definition under the adjective *rank*.

[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rank) has it as:

> Absolute; complete: *a rank amateur; rank treachery*. See Synonyms at
> [flagrant](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=F5161900).

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rank) as well:

> 2
>
> a: shockingly conspicuous
>
> *must lecture him on his rank disloyalty*— David Walden
>
> b: outright
>
> —used as an intensive
>
> *rank beginners*

Whenever *rank insubordination* is used, it's pretty clear that *rank* is a synonym of *flagrant*, *outright*, *shockingly conspicuous*. E.g.:

> The spat between the IPS and cadre officers in the CRPF and BSF has
> become a ridiculous spectacle, a battle about naked ambition to corner
> top posts. It's been a wonder how the top brass of an armed force
> handling sensitive national security assignments has tolerated such
> **rank insubordination**. An inquiry is too mild a proceeding, in the army
> such actions lead to a court martial. (Comment at [The Print](https://theprint.in/india/governance/crpf-begins-inquiry-against-top-officer-who-accused-ips-of-bias-after-being-transferred/435083/))

> “This looks like the last straw,” a seething President Harry Truman  scrawled in his diary on April 6, 1951. Once again the commander of
> U.S. forces in the Korean War, General Douglas MacArthur, had gone
> public with his differences with the commander in chief over the
> conduct of the war—this time in a letter to House Republican Leader
> Joseph Martin.
>
> Truman thought it nothing less than “**rank insubordination**,” and five
> days later he delivered the shocking news to the American people that
> he had relieved MacArthur of his command and replaced him with General
> Matthew Ridgway. ([History](https://www.history.com/news/macarthur-vs-truman-the-showdown-that-changed-america))

> the City contended that the plaintiffs were terminated for "**rank
> insubordination**" ([US Court of Appeals](https://www.ca5.uscourts.gov/opinions/unpub/91/91-7341.0.wpd.pdf))

If any of these had *rank* as a noun, it would be entirely unnecessary as insubordination is always from a lower rank. *Rank* is clearly used to express the degree of the insubordination and hence fits the definitions cited.

Comment: Yet again, I find myself upvoting your answer while closevoting to migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers On this one, I'll agree that the asker should have done their research. Vote away!

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is incorrect. I didn't say that I couldn't find any definition that fit; I said that I found *multiple* definitions that plausibly fit, and I couldn't find any explanation of *which* one was correct. To your comment: I'm unclear on what additional research I could have done. I found the intensifier definition that you claim, but I don't see any evidence that that is a more plausible meaning than the two that I suggested.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for why your proposed meaning is any more likely than the two that I suggested?

Comment: @tparker The context in which _rank insubordination_ is used makes it perfectly clear which of the definitions for _rank_ is fitting. See examples.

Comment: @tparker If you look at the examples for "foul or offensive", they presumably refer to something that smells bad. After someone exercises, you can say they're rank and need a shower.

Comment: The Etymologyonline entry at https://www.etymonline.com/word/rank seems to suggest that the modern meaning as a pejorative intensifier is connected to an earlier meaning of "vigorous, abundant" which was applied to plant growth. This sense also developed into the meaning of "foul, offensive". Both "abundant" and "offensive" would seem applicable to "rank insubordination".